# Setting a picture for button i made in XML (Android)?

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm having this question about setting pictures for Buttons in XML :

I made some .png pictures I want to set as pictures instead of the buttons that I get in default when i create my android apps.. Now I loaded in the files into the drawable folder.. And how do I write in XML to get the right thing?

Is setting the button visible to false and adding a picture as background for it an option?
Because that's all the ways I thought about.  Or is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I understood is that you want to set the picture in background. Do it like this in your Button tag:

```
android:background="@drawable/yourpicturename"
```

Comment: How can i make the button be larger but still be available for many devices ??

Comment: If you want to use the image size then use "wrap_content" or if you want to fill the screen you should use "fill_parent" for width and height....

Comment: Ok now its all good but one last problem.. How can i add spaces between the buttons?? They are all sticked together now in my relative layout..

Comment: set android:layout_margin="value in dp" for all left, top , bottom and right for common or you can specify separately android:layout_marginTop="value in dp", android:layout_marginLeft="value in dp", android:layout_marginBottom="value in dp", android:layout_marginRight="value in dp"

Answer (score 1):

Add the png to the **drawable** folder that is under the **res** folder in your project (if you are using eclipse). Then in your XML file simply use `android:background="@drawable/filename"`. Make sure to omit the file extension

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of:

drawableTop, drawableLeft, drawableRight, drawableBottom

For example,

```
<Button android:drawableRight="@drawable/some_image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Some text" />
```

The image some_image.png will be positioned to the right of your text in this case.

Comment: I did this but now the image is realy small even its sized for mdpi can i make it larger in some way?

Comment: I've never run into any sizing issues when using this.  Is your screen mdpi?  Is your resource in the 

'res/drawable-mdpi' directory?  You could also check in any other res/drawable directories to see if a smaller version of your image is there?  

Otherwise, if that's not the issue, I guess one workaround that I hate suggesting is setting the size of your button via layout_height and layout_width to the desired size (32dip, for example).